# Can Gazebo be made repeatable?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

For testing purposes I would like to ensure that my world is in exactly the same state at each time tick every time I launch the simulation.  I found the --seed flag but I'm still seeing randomness.  Is it possible to make a repeatable simulation in Gazebo?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/23014/can-gazebo-be-made-repeatable?/) by [Jenny B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/12896/jenny-b/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-06-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I had an asynchronous process call.  Using the seed flag does in fact make repeatable results for gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [Jenny B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/12896/jenny-b/) with karma: 13 on 2019-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0